# Avoiding loss of object instance in externally called prototypal method

Tags: javascript, prototype

The technique used by object `c` below to get past the loss of object instance `b` smells a bit to me. Is there a more accepted way?

```
function A()  {
    this.prop = "cat";
}

A.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log(this.prop);
}

function B() {}

B.prototype.test = function(meth) {
    meth();
}

function C() {}

C.prototype.test = function(obj, meth) {
    obj[meth]();
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var c = new C();

//tests
b.test(a.test);     // undefined
c.test(a, 'test');  // cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

**The this variable**

In all the example code you'll see `this` referring to the current instance.

The this variable actually refers to the invoking object, it refers to the object that came before the function.

To clarify see the following code:

```
theInvokingObject.thefunction();
```

The instances where this would refer to the wrong object are usually when attaching event listeners, callbacks or timeouts and intervals. In the next 2 lines of code we `pass` the function, we don't invoke it. Passing the function is: `someObject.aFunction` and invoking it is: `someObject.aFunction()`. The `this` value does not refer to the object the function was declared on but on the object that `invokes` it.

```
setTimeout(someObject.aFuncton,100);//this in aFunction is window
somebutton.onclick = someObject.aFunction;//this in aFunction is somebutton
```

To make `this` in the above cases refer to someObject you can pass a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) instead of the function directly:

```
setTimeout(function(){someObject.aFuncton();},100);
somebutton.onclick = function(){someObject.aFunction();};
```

I like to define functions that return a function for closures on the prototype to have fine control over the variables that are included in the closure scope.

```
var Hamster = function(name){
  var largeVariable = new Array(100000).join("Hello World");
  // if I do 
  // setInterval(function(){this.checkSleep();},100);
  // then largeVariable will be in the closure scope as well
  this.name=name
  setInterval(this.closures.checkSleep(this),1000);
};
Hamster.prototype.closures={
  checkSleep:function(hamsterInstance){
    return function(){
      console.log(typeof largeVariable);//undefined
      console.log(hamsterInstance);//instance of Hamster named Betty
      hamsterInstance.checkSleep();
    };
  }
};
Hamster.prototype.checkSleep=function(){
  //do stuff assuming this is the Hamster instance
};

var betty = new Hamster("Betty");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to pass a string, you can still pass a function:

```
C.prototype.test = function(obj, meth) {
    meth.call(obj);
}

// ...

c.test(a, a.test);  // cat
```

`Function#call` calls a function explicitly setting `this` within the call to be the first argument you give `call`. (There's also `Function#apply`; the only difference is how you pass additional arguments for the function.)

But usually (not always) this is considered the caller's problem, and they would typically solve it either using `Function#bind` (on an ES5-enabled engine or with a shim):

```
c.test(a.test.bind(a));
```

...or using a closure:

```
c.test(function() {
    a.test();
});
```

...where in both cases, you just call `meth()` within `C.prototype.test`.

`Function#bind` creates a new function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` set to the value you pass into `bind` and then it returns that new function.

Related posts on my blog:

- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [Closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Very helpful answer as well and had trouble deciding which to give the tick to. Hopefully a personal thanks evens it up--thanks!